# Product export Missed half of the products

Tags: magento

I have try to export my products, actually in my site consists 20,000 products, but exported records consists only 6,000 products, what about my remaining products.

Comment: how you exported? From backend export feature or any custom script? Is there any errors? Sometimes the php max filesize may cause the issue?

Comment: Am using default export

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/l04zY.png

Comment: why mismatching products counts

Comment: It's just product id, It will be auto_increment

Comment: But actually in my site 15,000 products, but 6000 record found olny is a mistake

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?